# Unable to load DLL (Matlab Runtime ) from IIS 7

Tags: matlab, web-services, iis, dllnotfoundexception

Resources:

MATLAB 2014 (MCR 8.4 = Matlab Compiler Runtime). (X64)
VS 2010 
IIS7 Windows 2008R

Hello together,

I created a matlab script and already publsihed it as .NET dll (Via .NET Builder). Now I try to used that .dll in my web Service together with the MWArray. The MWArray.dll is important to convert the parameters from c# to matlab datatypes. When I publish the web Service on my IIS i get the following error when i executed the matlab function.

> Blockquote System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt8_4.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.mclmcrInitialize2(Int32 primaryMode)
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray.get__Inf()
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray..ctor(Int32 scalar)
>      at WS_Splitoptimizer.Service1.Execute(Int32 Targetvalue, Int32[] Good_chip_per_wafer, Int32[] Wcmp_id, Double Overshoot_threshold) in H:\Eigene Dateien\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WS_Splitoptimizer\WS_Splitoptimizer\WS_SplitOptimizer.asmx.cs:line 64
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The 'mclmcrrt8_4.dll' is the MCR .dll and it exist at the Server. I already give everyone full permisson to that file.

So my problem is that the IIS is not able to located the MCR location. Does anyone have an idea to solve that problem?

I'm out of ideas on things to check. Any ideas welcome!

Thanks in advance!